# Pandas- how to merge two dataframes with duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes that look like this:

DF1:

| SYEAR_NUM | PROVINCE | INDUSTRY | OCC | *COUNT* | COUNT_LCS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 |  | 26000 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 11 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 13 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 14 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 15 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 16 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 111 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 112 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 113 | 0 |  |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 114 | 0 |  |

DF2:

| OCC | noc_title | onet | onet_title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0011 Legislators | 11-1031.00 | Legislators |
| 12 | 0012 Senior government managers and officials | 11-1011.00 | Chief Executives |
| 12 | 0012 Senior government managers and officials | 11-1011.03 | Chief Sustainability Officers |
| 12 | 0012 Senior government managers and officials | 11-1021.00 | General and Operations Managers |
| 13 | 0013 Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services | 11-1011.03 | Chief Sustainability Officers |
| 14 | 0014 Senior managers - health, education, social and community services and membership organizations | 11-1011.00 | Chief Executives |

Right now, I am trying to merge the two dataframes based on the common column 'OCC'. However, there  is a 'one to many' relationship as sometimes, values are repeated for the 'OCC' in DF2.

When I try to merge using the following command: `df3 = pd.merge(DF1,DF2)`. I get the following result.

| SYEAR_NUM | PROVINCE | INDUSTRY | OCC | *COUNT* | COUNT_LCS | noc_title | onet | onet_title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 |  | 26000 |  |  | 51-6021.00 | Pressers, Textile, Garment, and Related Materials |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 |  | 17750 | -8250 |  | 51-6021.00 | Pressers,Textile,Garment and Related materials |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 |  |  | 99250 |  | 51-6021.00 | Pressers,Textile,Garment and Related materials |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 |  | 76250 | -23000 |  | 51-6021.00 | Pressers,Textile,Garment and Related materials |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 11 | 0 |  | 0011 Legislators | 11-1031.00 | Legislators |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 11 | 0 |  | 0011 Legislators | 11-1031.00 | Legislators |

Values get replicated for duplicated rows i.e. if 11 in 'OCC' has multiple matches in df2, then in the merged df, the corresponding '*COUNT*' value will get duplicated across all the rows containing 11 in 'OCC'. I want to see the corresponding value in '*COUNT*' to be reflected only in the first row where the 'OCC' values match and the rest of the matching rows should be blank.

I have tried aggregating values in df2 using group by and creating a new df however, pandas doesn't allow merging the new df since its an object and I am also unable to covert it into an integer as well. I have also tried specifying relationship as 'one to many' (`df3 = pd.merge(DF1,DF2, on = 'OCC', validate = 'one_to_many'`). However it states that merge keys are not unique in the dataset that's why it's not possible to use them.
Ideally, I would want something like this i.e. for instances where df2 has multiple 'OCC' for a single 'OCC' in df1, a new row is created for the same 'OCC' with the value of '_COUNT' being 0 in the new row.

| SYEAR_NUM | PROVINCE | INDUSTRY | OCC | *COUNT* | COUNT_LCS | noc_title | onet | onet_title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 11 | 10 |  | 0011 Legislators | 11-1031.00 | Legislators |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 11 | 0 |  | 0011 Legislators | 11-1031.00 | Legislators |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 13 | 5 |  | 0013 Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services | 11-1011.00 | Chief Executives |
| 2021 | British Columbia | 1133 | 13 | 0 |  | 0013 Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services | 11-1011.00 | Chief Executives |

Any advice on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you please provide your expected result? It helps to respond to your query in a better way

Comment: Apologies for the mistakes, I have updated the question now.